# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Workaround

Tags: from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту "PMBOK та PM ISO українською". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Варіанти:

- Обхідне рішення
- Обхідний шлях

Визначення терміну Workaround [там](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Workaround) таке:

> **Workaround.** An immediate and temporary response to an issue, for which a prior response had not been planned or was not effective. See also risk mitigation.

Answer (score 3):

Пропоную **манівець**.

На [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/):

> Англійсько-український словник сучасних термінів з ІТ 2001–2011 (linux.org.ua)
> **workaround** = манівець {?}, тимчасове рішення {?}

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/manivci):

> **МАНІВЦІ,** ів, *мн.* (*одн.* манівець, вця, *чол.*). Кружний, обхідний шлях.